# Invert axis from a Matplotlib figure problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, size, figure

I have a Matplotlib figure that I inverted with the command: `ax.set_ylim(224, 0)`. I would like to know how to keep the figure inverted even when defining the figure size with: `plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))`

Without the `plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))` I was obtaining:

[image: Matplotlib figure]

And with the plt.fig:

[image: Matplotlib figure 2]

The code I'm using is:

```
x = np.arange(431) 
y = np.arange(225)
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x)
values = df["Appearance_percentage"].values 
values2d = np.reshape(values,(431,225)) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(224, 0)
plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
c1 = plt.contourf(X, Y, values2d, 50, cmap='bwr')
c2 = plt.contour(X, Y, values2d, 50, colors="k", linewidths=0.4)
plt.colorbar(c1)
plt.savefig("contourmap.png", dpi=800)
plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))`.  Your problem is that `plt.subplots` creates a figure, and `plt.figure` creates a new figure (erasing the earlier one).  Also, it's recommended to use `ax.contour()` etc instead of the `plt.contour()` versions.